# Python: split this length-structured string the most elegant way

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, split

Given this string:

```
fsw="M525x617M525x617S16d48492x577S10000505x544S22a00506x524S21300487x601S37601511x574S34500482x483
```

I'd like to convert

```
fsw[8:] (thus "M525x617S16d48492x577S10000505x544S22a00506x524S21300487x601S37601511x574S34500482x483")
```

in a dictionary containing:

```
{'S16d48':'492x577', 'S10000':'505x544', 'S22a00':'506x524', 'S21300':'487x601', 'S37601':'511x574', 'S34500':'482x483'}
```

I managed to get the following with regexp:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("S[123][0-9a-f]{2}[0-5][0-9a-f]",fsw[8:])
['S16d48', 'S10000', 'S22a00', 'S21300', 'S37601', 'S34500']

>>> re.findall("S[123][0-9a-f]{2}[0-5][0-9a-f].......",fsw[8:])
['S16d48492x577', 'S10000505x544', 'S22a00506x524', 'S21300487x601', 'S37601511x574', 'S34500482x483']
```

but as far as a dictionary is concerned... I failed to get any further.

> Another question: in a Python dictionary it is well the whole
>   key-value pair (say "S16d48":"492x577") that must be unique right ?

In advance - thanks a lot.
Regards.

Comment: Are keys and values fixed length?

Comment: Yes you will always find in fsw[8:] first 6 characters with pattern S[123][0-9a-f]{2}[0-5][0-9a-f] then 7 characters like YYYxZZZ with YYY and ZZZ being numbers ('x' always in the middle). Therefore 13 characters or more, always will be a multiple of 13.

Comment: If they are fixed, the pattern doesn't matter isn't it? You don't need to use regex, just iterate over those splitting points. See @ctenar's answer. For the second question, key should be unique, value doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can alter your expression to

```
(?P<key>S[123][0-9a-f]{2}[0-5][0-9a-f])
(?P<value>\d+x\d+)
```

And then do a dict comprehension as in

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'(?P<key>S[123][0-9a-f]{2}[0-5][0-9a-f])(?P<value>\d+x\d+)')

data = "M525x617M525x617S16d48492x577S10000505x544S22a00506x524S21300487x601S37601511x574S34500482x483"

result = {m["key"]: m["value"] for m in rx.finditer(data)}
```

This yields

```
{'S16d48': '492x577', 'S10000': '505x544', 'S22a00': '506x524', 'S21300': '487x601', 'S37601': '511x574', 'S34500': '482x483'}
```

---

See a demo for the expression [**on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/LR4hRC/1) and for the code on [**ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/0eXVf7).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the lists you already created to a dictionary in the following way:

```
import re

fsw="M525x617M525x617S16d48492x577S10000505x544S22a00506x524S21300487x601S37601511x574S34500482x483"
str_lst = re.findall("S[123][0-9a-f]{2}[0-5][0-9a-f]",fsw[8:])
full_lst = re.findall("S[123][0-9a-f]{2}[0-5][0-9a-f].......",fsw[8:])
str_dict = {x: y[len(x):] for x in str_lst for y in full_lst if y.startswith(x)}
```

This gives:

```
{'S16d48': '492x577',
 'S10000': '505x544',
 'S22a00': '506x524',
 'S21300': '487x601',
 'S37601': '511x574',
 'S34500': '482x483'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have understood what you are trying to do, but one way to obtain your dictionary from that string is

```
d = {}
for piece in fsw[8:].split('S')[1:]:
    d["S"+piece[:5]] = piece[5:]

print(d)
```