# Mix list comprehension on character split and int() conversion...?

Tags: python, list, int

Given following variable:

```
fsw="M543x620S30006482x483S14c10520x483S14c51498x537S14c39492x593S20500496x582S22a04494x564"
```

if I do this:

```
z=[sub.split('x') for sub in re.findall("\d{3}x\d{3}",fsw[8:])]
```

it returns :

```
[['482', '483'],  ['520', '483'],   ['498', '537'], ['492', '593'], ['496', '582'], ['494', '564']]
```

but I'd like to get a list of pairs of **integers** `([[482,483],[520,483],...])`. Is there a one-liner that would do this operation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Change `sub.split('x')` into `list(map(int, sub.split('x')))`?

Comment: Would ```z = [[int(y) for y in sub.split('x')] for sub in re.findall("\d{3}x\d{3}",fsw[8:])]``` not work?

Comment: Didn't we have the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938480/python-split-this-length-structured-string-the-most-elegant-way) yesterday? Please (re-)read the conventions of `StackOverflow` and upvote/accept answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
z=[map(lambda x: int(x), sub.split('x')) for sub in re.findall("\d{3}x\d{3}",fsw[8:])]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more the answer for your solution?